# Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate service 'SQLConnConfig'

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor

I am using blazor web assembly hosted. In Project.Client, I have the following files under data folder.

myProject.Client/Data/SQLConnConfig.cs:

```
public class SQLConnConfig
{
    public string Value  { get; }
    public SQLConnConfig(string value) => Value = value; 
}
```

myProject.Client/Data/MyService.cs:

```
public class MyService
{
    public static SQLConnConfig _conn;

    public SqlConnection connection;
    public MyService(SQLConnConfig conn)
    {
        _conn = conn;
        connection = new SqlConnection(_conn.Value);
    }

    public List<Item> GetItem()
    {
      ......
    }
```

myProject.Client/Data/Item.cs:

```
public class Item
{
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }          
        public string Name{ get; set; }           
}
```

Registered service in MyProject.Client/program.js

```
        builder.Services.AddScoped<MyService>();
```

In myProject.Server/startup.cs:

```
        var sqlConnConfig = new SQLConnConfig(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        services.AddSingleton<SQLConnConfig>(sp => sqlConnConfig);
        services.AddServerSideBlazor(x => x.DetailedErrors = true);
        services.AddSingleton<MyService>();
```

App setting has connection string included.

In the index.razor: I inject and use the service.

```
 @inject MyService MyService    
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
    result = MyService.GetItem();
 }
```

I get an error saying "Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.Client.Data.SQLConnConfig". May I know where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you intend on getting the connection string from? I noticed you commented out the code in startup that was setting the constructor. The code in program.cs is adding the class by default which is a problem since the container wont know how to get the string. hence the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide your `SQLConnConfig` class like this:

```
 var sqlConnConfig = new SQLConnConfig(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

 builder.Services.AddScoped<SQLConnConfig>(sp => sqlConnConfig );
```

No need for `static` in   `public static SQLConnConfig _conn;`

The error is coming from injection trying to construct the SQLConnConfig class.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. When I try, I get error on CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); saying "Cannot consume scoped service 'Myproject.Client.Data.SQLConnConfig' from singleton 'Myproject.Client.DataMyService'.

Comment: I have added these lines on MyProject.server/startup.cs. Config and service files are in MyProject.client/Data/.

Comment: @Sarahrb if you are injecting into a singleton change the `AddScoped<>` to `AddSingleton<>` You can inject a singleton into scoped not the other way around. You should read up on the different lifecycles Scoped, Transient, and Singleton.

Comment: Now, it says cannot provide a value for property 'MyService' on type 'MyProject.Client.Pages.Index'. There is no registered service of type 'MyProject.Client.Data.MyService'

Comment: This happens when it tries to call MyService in index.razor page. Does this mean, I need to register on the client project as well? in client program.js? This is webassembly hosted project fyi. Have three projects underneath(client, server and shared).

Comment: Have edited code above. If I keep AddScoped<MyService> line on MyProject.Client\program.cs. I get unable to resolve service for type 'MyProject.Client.Data.SQLConnConfig' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.Client.Data.RunLogService'.

Comment: I would appreciate if I can get suggestion on why this new error happens. WASM target framework is .NET5.0.

Comment: @Sarahrb Are you trying to inject a service in your client app that is defined on the server? ...

Comment: All files used are defined inside client. (myProject.Client/Data/). Only for injecting  MyService and sqlConnConfig, I use (myProject.Server).

Comment: I would recommend using an API on the server and the database connection on the server. A connection string in a client is very dangerous.

Comment: Connection string and database connection happens only on the server now, (in appsettings and startup.cs) of server app. Am I understanding it wrong.